# Runnable vs Service; Lifespan explained with use-cases

Tags: android, android-service, runnable

As I understand - both Runnable and Service are intended to run piece of code in background. My code structure is this:

1. BaseManager.class which is implemented as Singleton and using BaseManager.getInstance() will return single instance in application. Also, when first initialized it automatically creates SmallerAndCompletelyDifferentManager.class - has a dependency.
2. SmallerAndCompletelyDifferentManager.class - creates a Runnable that runs every 2 seconds.

Now, I've two scenerios:

**SCENERIO A:** I create initialize BaseManager.class in Activity first and use it wherever I need. The Runnable that is inside SmallerAndCompletelyDifferentManager.class runs okay, but as I understand is attached to Activity - if Activity dies, so will the Runnable which I can not afford.

**SCENERIO B:** I create a foreground service and initialize BaseManager.class. Does this mean that now the Runnable will work as intended - even if application is in background and Activity has been destroyed?

Am I getting this right or no? The overall plan is to make sure that Runnable survives in background at all costs.

Comment: You are on right track but there is difference between Service and Runnable. To put things **Service is one of the component in Android just like Activity** whereas **Runnable interface should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread**. So basically Service and Activity executes on mainThread/UIThread and they provide context. If you need to execute some task on thread other then mainThread you can go for Runnable. This mean Activity/Service might have Runnable, but if Activity/Service is killed then thread started using Runnable will also die.

Comment: I would say to go with **SCENARIO B**. About the thing that ' Runnable survives in background at all costs' is not possible because everything you do from application is attached to it's process and if process gets killed it's your responsibility to restart stuffs you want. In your case, Runnable thing in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand - both Runnable and Service are intended to run piece
>   of code in background

This is not correct.

`Service` is an application component that can be perform long-running operations in the background. Here background means you do something behind the scene (or background) when users interact with the app, or when users switch to another apps.

`Runnable` is a block of code that can be run, that why it has the name "Runnable", it means something can be run/execute. The Runnable interface **should be** implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread.

In Android there a two types of thread, the first one is main/UI thread and another one is background thread. Here background means when you do something in a thread rather than main/UI thread.

Back to your case

**In scenario 1:** The Activity creates Runnable and keep a reference to it. When you destroy the activity (by press Back button or call `finish()` method), the activity will be destroyed, and the runnable will be released.

**In scenario 2:** The foreground service creates Runnable and keep a reference to it. When you destroy activity or switch to another apps, the service is still alive (and runnable as well) until you kill service by calling (`stopSelft()` or `stopService()` method). Because when using a foreground service, it will tell the system that the app is doing something important and it shouldn’t be killed.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand - both Runnable and Service are intended to run piece
>   of code in background.

To be more specific, [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) runs on a main thread. It is your responsibility to put the work on a separate thread if you are planning to make a CPU-intensive work inside the service. You can do so by putting it inside a `Runnable` or a `Thread`.

> Am I getting this right or no? The overall plan is to make sure that
>   Runnable survives in background at all costs.

Scenario B could work but my suggestion is to modify your `BaseManager` into a service class.